# Can we compute edit distance in strongly sub-quadratic time?

Tags: algorithms, string-metrics, edit-distance

Can we compute the edit distance between two strings of length $n$ in strongly sub-quadratic time, i.e., in time $O(n^{2−\epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon>0$?

Comment: Diptarka Chakraborty, Debarati Das, E. Goldenberg, M. Koucky, M. Saks: [***Approximating** Edit Distance Within Constant Factor in Truly Sub-Quadratic Time*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03664).